# Error with dbFD() function

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate functional diversity indices (FDiv, FDis and FEve) using FD package. The dataset is 297 species by 24 binary traits as matrix x and species X 76 sites as a matrix. I could not run `dbFD()` function since I received the species names are not in the same order in both datasets. However, I checked it for several times. As there are some problems with this function some times in Windows system I just tried to run another function. However, it is somehow the same as `dbFD()`.

I could calculate FDis for 76 sites using:

```
disp <- fdisp(x.dist, a)
FDis <- disp$FDis
```

but have problem with the following functions:

```
# calculate nbsp, FRic, FEve, FDis, and FGR
# definition of vector for results, with communities'names as given in 'a'

nbsp <- rep(NA, c) ; names(nbsp) <- row.names(a)
FRic <- rep(NA, c) ; names(FRic) <- row.names(a)
FEve <- rep(NA, c) ; names(FEve) <- row.names(a)
FGR <- rep(NA, c) ; names(FGR) <- row.names(a)
FDiv <- rep(NA, c) ; names(FDiv) <- row.names(a)
```

After running I receive this error:

> Error: cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'integer'

Any suggestion will help me for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `rep` expects an integer value as second parameter but `c` is the name of a builtin `R` function. Thus,

```
rep(NA, c)
```

is causing the error message.

As it is never a good idea to overwrite basic `R` functions, I suggest to try something along

```
n <- length(row.names(a))
nbsp <- rep(NA, n)
names(nbsp) <- row.names(a)
...
```

Comment: @Halime Great new, thank you for the feedback. Please, be so kind to accept my answer by clicking on the tickmark on the left side. Thank you.

Comment: Dear Uwe,thanks for your message. Since I am a newcomer in Stack overflow I did not know that I have to click the tickmark. Thanks to notice me.

Comment: @Halime, Thank you for accepting my answer. In SO, you can earn reputation when your answer is being accepted. (Reputation is expressed in the number that appears underneath your user name) In addition, you can earn or lose reputation when other users upvote or downvote your questions or answers by clicking on the triangles to the left. More details in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). The more reputation points you have the more privileges you will gain, eg, to post links, to place comments everywhere, etc. Hope, you will find the explanation helpful.